# XlsxWriter can't set header

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

This code works for all lines expect the 3 `set_header`s()
Any thoughts?

```
ws.set_print_scale(40)
ws.set_header('&L&F')
ws.set_header('&CNewCo Inc.')
ws.set_header('&R&D')
ws.set_portrait()

f1h = wb.add_format()
ws.set_column(0, 0, 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should issue a *single* `set_header()` command instead:

```
ws.set_header('&L&F &CNewCo Inc. &R&D')
```

Comment: You the MAN!  Much much thanks.  In fact I now see the last set_header() actually was working but before I post this question I didn;t notice for some reason.